# Download files from s3 according to my OS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation

Need help building a Bash script which will be able to have connection in it with "Secret key" + "Access key" to the S3 bucket and will download specific exe file from the bucket if there are specific OS for it.
For example:
If my OS is Amazon Linux 2, it will download X file from X folder.
And if my OS is Centos 6 or 7 or 8, it will download other files, and like that with Windows and etc..

and at the end execute this file.

Any help will be appreciated, i always used to do it manually with individual commands like "aws s3 sync" or aws configure to connect the secret and access key, but now I'm trying to run it across multiple accounts and want to build some automation.

Thanks for help.

Comment: (1) you check `$OSTYPE` & then within it use `uname -a` for version (2) main bash associative array of os_type+version as key and value as your aws s3 bucket path (3) based on conditions from step 1 figure out aws s3 bucket to use

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you to not use the awscli tools when dealing with multiple accounts.  As seen in the docs under [Named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html):

> The following example shows a credentials file with two profiles. The first `[default]` is used when you run a CLI command with no profile. The second is used when you run a CLI command with the `--profile user1` parameter.
>
> `~/.aws/credentials` (Linux & Mac) or `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` (Windows)
>
> ```
> [default]
> aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
> aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
>
> [user1]
> aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
> aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
> ```

This also applies to the `~/.aws/config` file, but you don't need entries in there unless you want to override the region or the encoding on a user-by-user basis.

So, make a bunch of entries in your `~/.aws/credentials` for each account and then loop through each of those accounts with whatever `aws s3` commands you had in mind.

Comment: awscli tools is great, but i want to automate this script in aws systems manager, and build a document with it and run it in automation.